# Copy data from one Spreadsheet to another keeping format and without formulas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm looking to do is to copy a data range from one Spreadsheet to another while preserving formats (colors, styling, etc.) and only taking the values without the formulas.

I already have this code (from a previous answer from @Tanaike), with a bit of modifications. It preserves the formatting but copies the formulas and I only need the values.

```
//Source
var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID).getSheetByName(sheetName);
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(range);

//Destination
var destSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newID);
var destSheet = destSS.getSheets()[0];
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(range);
destSheet.clear();

//var copiedsheet = sourceRange.getSheet().copyTo(destSS); // <-- This works, but copies formulas and get Ref errors
var copiedsheet = sourceRange.getSheet().copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true}); //Doesn't work, I tried many variations of this

copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false); // Will preserve formatting
destSS.deleteSheet(destSS.getSheets()[0]);

DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolder).addFile(docFile);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `range` of `var destRange = destSheet.getRange(range);` and `var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(range);` is not declared.
- Method of `copyTo` in Class Range cannot be used for other Google Spreadsheet. It seems that this is the current specification. I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- And, for example, when IMPORTRANGE is used in the source sheet as the formula, when `sourceRange.getSheet().copyTo(destSS)` is used, the values cannot be shown because of the authorization. Also I'm worry about this.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `sourceID`, `sheetName` and `newID`. And, please set `range` as the A1Notation.

```
//Source
var sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
var sourceSheet = sourceSS.getSheetByName(sheetName);
var tempSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(sourceSS);
var temoSheetRange = tempSheet.getRange(range);
temoSheetRange.copyTo(temoSheetRange, {contentsOnly: true});
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // This might not be required.

//Destination
var destSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(newID);
var destSheet = destSS.getSheets()[0];
destSheet.clear();
var destTempSheet = tempSheet.copyTo(destSS);
var destTempRange = destTempSheet.getRange(range);
var dstRange = destSheet.getRange("A1");
destTempRange.copyTo(dstRange);
destTempRange.copyTo(dstRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
var i = 1;
var row = destTempRange.getRow();
for (var r = row; r <= row + destTempRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
  destSheet.setRowHeight(i++, destTempSheet.getRowHeight(r));
}
destSS.deleteSheet(destTempSheet);
sourceSS.deleteSheet(tempSheet);
```

- I'm not sure your direction of `DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolder).addFile(docFile);` and `DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);` in your script. So in this modification, I don't show it. When you are required to use it, please add it.

#### Note:

- If you can copy only the row height except for the default height of `21` pixels, the cost of script might be reduced. If you use it, please modify as follows. In this modification, Sheets API is not used.

  - From

    ```
      for (var r = row; r <= row + destTempRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
        destSheet.setRowHeight(i++, destTempSheet.getRowHeight(r));
      }
    ```
  - To

    ```
      for (var r = row; r <= row + destTempRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
        var rowHeight = destTempSheet.getRowHeight(r);
        if (rowHeight != 21) destSheet.setRowHeight(i, rowHeight);
        i++;
      }
    ```
- Or, when you use Sheets API, you can also use the following modification. In this case, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services.

  - From

    ```
      var i = 1;
      var row = destTempRange.getRow();
      for (var r = row; r <= row + destTempRange.getNumRows(); r++) {
        destSheet.setRowHeight(i++, destTempSheet.getRowHeight(r));
      }
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var reqs = [];
      var sheetId = destSheet.getSheetId();
      var reqs = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(newID, {ranges: [destTempSheet.getSheetName()], fields: "sheets(data(rowMetadata))"}).sheets[0].data[0].rowMetadata.reduce((ar, {pixelSize}, r) => {
        if (pixelSize != 21) ar.push({updateDimensionProperties:{range:{sheetId:sheetId,dimension:"ROWS",startIndex:r,endIndex:r+1},properties:{pixelSize:pixelSize},fields:"pixelSize"}});
        return ar;
      }, []);
      if (reqs.length > 0) Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: reqs}, newID);
    ```

#### References:

- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination, options) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: Thank for your answer Tanaike. Just as a note, my code is a function that receives the parameters like range (for example: B2:B22), also destRange and sourceRange are used at the end of the code.

Comment: Your code did work, but it did not preserve the column widths like before. I know I have to add SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS inside the copyTo parameters, but I'm unsure in which one. Thanks again.

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your situation, you want to copy the specific range in the source sheet to destination sheet. And also, you want to also keep the column width. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct. I want to copy an specific range and keep the column/row widths. This is because I have some text inside a cell, and if it doesn't preserve the width it won't look good and it would be hard to read. On my previous code this line was preserving the format: `copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);` , but I'm unsure on where to put this in your code.

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. This works. Maybe I won't use the loop to set the row heights because it makes the script a bit slow.

Comment: @Diego Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one modification point. Could you please confirm it? But I'm not sure whether that is the direction you expect. So if that was not the result you expect, I apologize.