# How to copy data to another worksheet based on checkbox?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet page in google sheets and I want every time I check the first line, that line will be moved to another Spreadsheet. I tried with the codes and it works great in the same spreadsheet. But in another spreadsheet (Same Google  account) it doesn't work. This is my codes.
[This is source link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q2WDhr9-kEk0E0Kd9vABI3HYQVRP-4J5T4ymWzubpeE/edit?usp=sharing)
[And I want move it here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpeX8COhb1CHhRXB85jcWLjIOIT7As8IHVfwmIcGb60/edit?usp=sharing)

```js
function onEdit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('管理シート');
  // var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("シート10");
  
  
  var cell=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()=="管理シート" && cell.getColumn()==1 && cell.getValue() == true){
    
    var row=cell.getRow();
    var range=sheet1.getRange(row,1,1,sheet1.getLastColumn());
    range.copyTo(sheet2.getRange((sheet2.getLastRow()+1),1));
    Logger.log('done');
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @Dmitry Kostyuk  This is error [ You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
    at onEdit(Code:5:29)]

Comment: I think that your 1st issue is due to that `openById` is used with the simple trigger. And also, I think that your script has the 2nd issue. Unfortunately, in the current stage, `copyTo` method cannot be used between Spreadsheet A and Spreadsheet B. I think that this is the reason of your 2nd issue. In this case, these threads might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/q/59462298 https://stackoverflow.com/q/66035463 And please use the installable OnEdit trigger.

Comment: @Tanaike After reviewing my source code and referencing your tutorial. Then it worked. I am very grateful to you for this. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.